# ngRepeat doesn't update custom element directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom element directive (`restrict: "E"`) which replaces the custom element with a new element that depends on scope (by handling `link`). This works fine but `ngRepeat` fails to remove such directives. It seems it can't find the target DOM element because it was replaced by the directive itself.

Code:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    <h3>Click an element to remove it</h3>
    <custom ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-click="remove(tag)"></custom>
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope) {
      $scope.tags = [
        { tagName: "button", text: "button" },
        { tagName: "div", text: "div" },
        { tagName: "span", text: "span" }
      ];

      $scope.remove = function(tag) {
        console.log("remove", tag.text);
        $scope.tags.splice($scope.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
      }
    }).directive("custom", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",        
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          var tag = angular.element("<" + scope.tag.tagName + ">").text(scope.tag.text);

          tag.attr("ng-click", attr.ngClick)

          $compile(tag)(scope);

          element.replaceWith(tag);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/somuzagaba/1/edit?html,output) (Try clicking the `button` and then the `div` - button doesn't disappear at first and then both the div and the button disappear). It works if instead of `element.replaceWith(tag)` I use `element.append(tag)`.

Can this somehow work? I need the directive to have custom tag name which depends on scope and also work with ngRepeat when an item is removed. Long story short I don't need the `<custom>` element in the DOM because of CSS rules I can't control. Something like `replace:true` which works with `link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes it is possible if one uses `transclude: 'element'`. Then angular gives the `link` function a comment DOM element which it later uses for DOM manipulations. Here is the relevant code:

```
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    transclude: "element",
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var tag = angular.element("<" + scope.tag.tagName + ">").text(scope.tag.text);

      tag.attr("ng-click", attr.ngClick)

      $compile(tag)(scope);

      element.after(tag); // insert after the comment node
    }
```

And a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/gutedicova/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Why u need replace?

```
 element.append(tag);
```

seem to [work ok](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNosDnXBi2hNujMqkuQ6?p=preview):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    <h3>Click an element to remove it</h3>
    <custom ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-click="remove(tag)"></custom>
    <br><br>{{tags}}  
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope) {
      $scope.tags = [
        { tagName: "button", text: "button" },
        { tagName: "div", text: "div" },
        { tagName: "span", text: "span" }
      ];

      $scope.remove = function(tag) {
        console.log("remove", tag.text);
        $scope.tags.splice($scope.tags.indexOf(tag), 1);
      }
    }).directive("custom", function($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: "E",        
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          var tag = angular.element("<" + scope.tag.tagName + ">").text(scope.tag.text);

          tag.attr("ng-click", attr.ngClick)

          $compile(tag)(scope);

          element.append(tag);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because of CSS rules I can't control. The extra wrapper element breaks certain CSS rules (direct descendant). I just don't need that `<custom>` element in the DOM. Something like `replace:true` which works together with `link`

Comment: This should not be an answer, but a comment. The OP specified in the question that `element.append` works